# Java Script AG Grid getting row node id

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-validation

I am new to Java Script and I working on implementing AG-Grid. I got stuck at how to get a row node id for selected row in AG grid?

Comment: Could you please show us the code that you are working on?

Comment: In order to help you, we need to know when do you need the row node id? Is it when you click on the row? Is from an external UI that needs to know the selected node ids? What is the scenario?